# Jsoup -- iterate over multiple elements simultaneously?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am attempting to convert an html page with entries that have multiple types of details (e.g. name, phone number, and address), into a spreadsheet. I am able to to isolate each of these details as Elements, but I cannot seem to find a way to iterate over multiple Elements at once to print names and phone numbers next to one another rather than having all the names printed and then all of the phone numbers printed.

```
Jsoup.connect(page).timeout(999999);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(page).get();
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println(title);

        Elements names = doc.select("li a");
        Elements ratings = doc.select("li img");

        for (Element name:names){
            if (name.attr("href").startsWith("/biz/")){
            System.out.println(name.text());
            }


            for (Element rating:ratings){

                System.out.println(rating.attr("alt"));

        }
```

Comment: it would help if you gave the html you are feeding to JSoup as well. at least the relevant parts

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the index its the same for both this would work fine.

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.size() && i < ratings.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println("Name: " + names.get(i) + " Phone: " +  ratings.get(i));
}
```